# How to send array of dictionarys of JSON in SWIFT - (POST method)

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, post

I want to know how I can send more than one array of dictionary in JSON. I have to do POST in this format :

```
{
  "Account":
  {
    "lastname":"VVV",
    "PersonEmail":"vaaaay@gmail.com"
  },
  "Member":
  {
    "Password__C":"12345"
  },
  "ProgramName":"My Chili's"
}
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
  lname = lastName.text!
        fname = firstName.text!
        email = emailSignUp.text!
        pass = passwordSignup.text!

        let signUpDict : [String:Any] =
       [
            "Account": [
            "lastname": lname!,
            "PersonEmail": email!
            ],

            "Member": [
                "Password__C": pass!
            ],

            "ProgramName": "My Chilli's"
        ]



var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.setValue("application/json;application/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
do{
    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: signUpDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    urlRequest.httpBody = postData

}
catch {
    print("Couldnt post this")
}



let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:urlRequest as URLRequest){(data,response,error) in

    if error != nil{

        print("Error is \(error)")
        return
    }


    print("Data Responded : \(data)")
    print("response is: \(response)")

}

task.resume()
```

I am getting a 500 error in response.

```
{ status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "s-maxage=0";
    "Content-Security-Policy" = "referrer origin-when-cross-origin";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 01 Aug 2017 12:19:44 GMT";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} })
```

I think the way I have written the signUpDict could be incorrect or missing something, could someone please guide me through this?

**Edit:** 
As requested I tried the json on POSTMAN, however this is my first time using POSTMAN(complete newbie). So I am not sure if I did it right.

[POSTMAN screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90ppY.png)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. You might be formatting the `JSON` wrong, but without seeing how he expected `JSON` should look like, we can't help with it. One thing though, you shouldn't set the `Content-type` header to `"application/json;application/html; charset=utf-8"` if you only send `JSON`, so you should delete the `application/html` part.

Comment: I did this, however made no difference. Anything else I can try?

Comment: You should implement a working POST request in `Postman` and try to mimic the structure of that request. If you get it to work, but still can't figure out how to do it from `Swift`, please update your question with all the information from your working Postman request and I will have a look.

Comment: Remove `JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted`, that's quite useless. You may want to add content-lenght (sometimes it's not optional for servers).

Comment: @DávidPásztor I updated the POSTMAN. Please check. I should also add the same request works in php.

Comment: @Larme alright I will remove that, but I dont think it will affect the output.

Comment: @user161993 are you sure that request actually went through and returned a successful HTTP response? Judging from the fact that you got an error in your pre-request script, it looks like the request didn't even run. Completely delete the content of pre-request script, it seems like you inserted something there that you shouldn't have.

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes, thank you. I did it now(thank you for the quick lesson!). I have updated the POSTMAN screenshot, please check.

Comment: this is the get method and you calling post so please update first

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL this is the HTTP response data of the POST request, why would you assume, this is a GET request?

Comment: @user161993 your request body indeed looks the same as in Postman. Are the headers the same as well?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes, I added Content-Type application/json . Nothing else.

Comment: first solve this error in your service System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject\n\nClass.LOYWS_MemberServices.doPost: line 66, column 1 . because your service showing error in response

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL I dont see any error in response, where did you get this? POSTMAN Response works fine.

Comment: @user161993 if I try to use the same values as you provided in the screenshot, I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: i calle this api in my app using alamofire getting response with 200 code but showing error message like this so first verify you service code

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL Okay, I checked this on POSTMAN again, I dont get the error. What am I doing wrong? on app, its still response 500 for me.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thats weird, I tried on POSTMAN again. However since it is a webservice for signup, I think using same values might cause the error(However, I didnt get it. I got a response!). What am I doing differently?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes I printed response sting in my code and I got that error too. However, I cant see it on postman or on the php web app. The webservice goes through and I am still getting 500 response, Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's definitely something wrong on your web service if you receive 500 response code. You should get the code of your backend, since that's where the issue lies.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thank you for constantly following up with me, When I removed the unwrapping I did at "lastname": lname!,
            "PersonEmail": email!  , it worked for me. I assumed I was supposed to do this because they were OPTIONAL fields, I removed(!) and it worked, I also got a 200 response this time. Thank you for your inputs, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try to use this updated code

```
   lname = lastName.text!
   fname = firstName.text!
   email = emailSignUp.text!
   pass = passwordSignup.text!

   let signUpDict : [String:Any] =
    [
        "Account": [
            "lastname": lname!,
            "PersonEmail": email!
        ],

        "Member": [
            "Password__C": pass!
        ],

        "ProgramName": "My Chilli's"
   ]




    let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: signUpDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    if let json = json {
        print(json)
    }

    let jsonData = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpBody = jsonData
```

Comment: I did try this code. I had to change the request.httpMethod = "POST" as it was giving me an error, however, this still gave me 500 response.

Answer (score 0):

Replace following  line :

**From**

```
urlRequest.setValue("application/json;application/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

**To**

```
urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: I did this, however made no difference. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
lname = lastName.text!
   fname = firstName.text!
   email = emailSignUp.text!
   pass = passwordSignup.text!


let accountDict = NSMutableDictionary.init()
let memberDict = NSMutableDictionary.init()
let finalDict = NSMutableDictionary.init()
accountDict.setValue(lname, forKey: "lastname")
accountDict.setValue(email, forKey: "PersonEmail")
 memberDict.setValue(pass, forKey: "Password__C")
 finalDict.setValue(accountDict, forKey: "Account")
 finalDict.setValue(memberDict, forKey: "Member")
finalDict.setValue("My Chili's", forKey: "ProgramName")
print(finalDict)

let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: finalDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

    let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    if let json = json {
        print(json)
    }

    let jsonData = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue);

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpBody = jsonData
```